# Azure AD : Account doesn't exist when user exists in ADim

Tags: azure, synchronization, account, azure-active-directory

I'm implementing a local AD - Azure AD Sync on a project. As of right now, the ADs seem to be in sync, as the user accounts created in my local AD are correctly listed in the Azure AD. Yet, I can't manage to connect to, for example, apps.microsoft.com using said user account. User login info would look like namesurname@myazuredomain.onmicrosoft.com.
Yet I keep getting "That Microsoft account doesn't exist. Enter a different account or get a new one."

I then tried creating a user directly under Azure ID interface (on manage.windowsazure.com) and tried to login using its infos, it didn't recognize it either.

I've tried switching browsers and machine, logging out and in, it doesn't change anything.

Where else should I look ?

Edit : Turns out there is a latency between password modification on the local AD and Azure AD. Modified the password through Azure portal and was able to successfully login using incognito mode. Also add to add a user subscription to modify the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a latency between password modification on the local AD and Azure AD. Modified the password through Azure portal and was able to successfully login using incognito mode. Also add to add a user subscription to modify the password.